# pushManager.subscribe() is not fulfilling promise, stuck in pending

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

The problem is that the pushManager.subscribe() function is not working, the promise is not fulfilling, no error into, nothing. What is the problem?

```
async subscribe() {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)){
        return;
    }

    await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');

    const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;

    // pushManager.subscribe() is not fulfilling promise
    const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: "public-vapid-key"
    })

    await fetch("/api/push-notification-subscription", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    });
  }
```